# multiple query in one file - where to close mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Hello I have 2 query in one file (I have mysqli database class)

1 query is in if else

2 second query is not in if else

my question is where I must to close mysql?

```
<?php db::mysqli()->close(); ?>
```

Comment: Either when you're done with all of your queries, or not at all. The connection will close automatically when the script is done.

Comment: so I must close mysql end of my file?

Comment: You don't have to, since it will close on its own, but you can to free up some resources.

Comment: okey, but I do not understand, whay need mysqli close function if it closes automatic

Comment: Open non-persistent MySQL connections and result sets are automatically destroyed when a PHP script finishes its execution. So, while explicitly closing open connections and freeing result sets is optional, doing so is recommended. This will immediately return resources to PHP and MySQL, which can improve performance. For related information, see freeing resources. [src](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.close.php)

Comment: Gocha in case of real long scripts, where you want to free the resources ash a@aynber said. But considering most applications and today's computing capabilities...closing is not needed at all.

Comment: To enable a programmer to close a connection at will.

Comment: Thanks now I am understand.

Comment: (1): [Is closing the mysql connection important?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/880885/) (2): [Do I really need to do mysql_close()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3359716/) (3): [When should I close a database connection in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20492427/)