# PHP mysql : possible to check if a link is open?

Tags: php, mysql

Imagine the simple snippet below:

```
<?
mysql_close();
?>
```

This will obviously output the following warning (may look different depending on what version of php_mysql(i) you are using):

```
mysql_close(): no MySQL-Link resource supplied in .....
```

As there is no link open.

Is there a way in php to test if a mysql link is already established or not?

Thanks!

---

Note, have been getting a few comments regarding the use of mysql_close(). I just used that as an example. Furthermore, there are (many) situations when the use of mysql_close() is appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you keep track of the resource identifier, you can use `if ($link)` which will get destroyed if you call mysql_close and then it will no longer evaluate true.

Comment: Yea I thought about that, but as it stands now, we do not track the identifier. Will look into implementing this.

Comment: So far this looks like the best way of doing this without doing something dirty like if(!@mysql_close()){ echo 'close failed, assume no connection...'; }

Answer (score 0):

well i'm not sure but see the answer here

[Is closing the mysql connection important?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/880885/close-mysql-connection-important)

> From the [documentation](http://us.php.net/function.mysql-connect):
>
> Note: The link to the server will be closed as soon as the execution of the script ends, unless it's closed earlier by explicitly calling mysql_close().

Answer (score 0):

If you need reconnect to mysql, look at this function:
http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.mysql-ping.php