# How does PHP interacts with MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, logic

Can someone explain me how does PHP interacts with MySQL. I want to know when I make queries using `mysql_query` when the connection is closed. Or should I use `mysql_close()`...

I thought that the connection is open while the page is being interpret and closes when it's done with interpreting.

Comment: ... closing it manually seems to be a good practice to follow: [enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/880885/close-mysql-connection-important

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The connection remains open from the `mysql_connect` call until either:

- `mysql_close` is called
- the reference to the connection (`$db = mysql_connect...`) is unset (with `unset`, or falls out of scope)
- the script finishes executing

Answer (score 2):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-close.php

You don't need to close explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Use `mysql_close()` only if you are concerned about size of the transfer. If it is not huge, you are OK without it.