# php mysql mysql_connect and closed connections

Tags: php, mysql, mysql-connect

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is closing the mysql connection important?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/880885/is-closing-the-mysql-connection-important)

Edit - the above is not the same question and does not answer my question here.
Here I speak specifically about the case that you DONT issue a query on the opened connection and I further ask what governs this closing, neither of which are addressed in the above answer.

If you use mysql_connect to connect to a database then don't issue a query on the database for a couple minutes, is the connection automatically closed?
And if so, what governs this closing?

Thanks

Comment: The connection will close after a certain amount of time. [**Don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](http://j.mp/XqV7Lp). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which

Comment: Thanks, this is an old project I am maintaining, but I note your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the connection will be closed at the end of the script.

From php.net

> Using mysql_close() isn't usually necessary, as non-persistent open links are automatically closed at the end of the script's execution.

Comment: My connection is being closed before the end of the script and before any query is issued on it.