# Is it necessary to close a mySQL connection [e.g. with mysqli_close()], if so WHEN and WHY?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, database-connection

I've seen some posts that about debugging errors associated with `mysqli_close()`, more then once ive users have responded saying that it is not really necessary to close a connection?

If its not necessary, **why have a function for it**?

If it is, **why and when is this important**?

Comment: Was going to vote to close as duplicate with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/880885/is-closing-the-mysql-connection-important but Robert beat me to it.

Comment: Sorry, i did search before posting... not well enough though.

Comment: My Google Search was "mysqli_close".  The duplicate was the third search result.

Comment: I searched on the stackoverflow search bar... i'll stick with google next time.