# Should I keep a db connection open in MySQLdb?

Tags: python, mysql, twitter

I am writing a script in python to listen to the twitter streaming api which will track specific keywords and insert them in mysql database using MySQLdb. I am not sure which way to choose:

1. For each incoming tweet, open a db connection, insert to db, then close the connection.
2. Open a db connection and execute insert command for incoming tweets and not closing the connection at all.

I think the script will receive 1-10 tweets per second.

Comment: check first answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/880885/is-closing-the-mysql-connection-important in summary, if you are not doing any processing besides saving to the database, don't close the connection

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It kind of depends on how your script is supposed to be run, but it *should* close the connection at some point - at least once when the process dies. Assuming it's a long-running process (daemon etc), the simplest strategy would be to use a "with" block to ensure the connection is closed, ie:

```
with MySQLdb.connect(**kw) as db:
    while some_condition():
        do_stuff_with(db)
```

but you'll probably need something a bit more involved since MySQL tends to [close idle connections by itself](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/gone-away.html)