# PHP MySQL Connections Closed

Tags: php, mysql

Something I have always wondered, it seems that virtually no PHP applications ever explicitly close MySQL connections `mysqli_close()`.

How does this work? Does PHP automagically close MySQL connections when scripts stop executing?

Comment: refer to this answer! --> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1351633/why-use-mysqli-close

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the connection will be closed unless it is a persistent connection (opened with a [`p:` before the host](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php#refsect1-mysqli.construct-parameters)). Non-persistent resources are freed automatically at the end of the script, because there are no more references to them.

[From the PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.resource.php#language.types.resource.self-destruct):

> Thanks to the reference-counting system introduced with PHP 4's Zend Engine, a resource with no more references to it is detected automatically, and it is freed by the garbage collector. For this reason, it is rarely necessary to free the memory manually.